# Magento guest checkout option not showing up regardless of allow guest checkout setting

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, checkout

I’m having a strange problem with my fresh magento installation. There is no option for guest checkout even though I have Disable Onepage Checkout: NO, and Allow Guest Checkout: YES.

I’ve looked at the core_config_data in the db and can’t find anything that would instigate this behavior. I have no template customizations and have disabled cache… I installed the latest magento via command line ssh and included the sample data pack. I installed another copy of magento on my local machine (without the test data) and it is working fine. Perhaps it has something to do with the sample data??

I’m at a loss here… Ideas anyone??

Answer (score 13):

I got this problem too, I could see the Guest option again when I removed the cookie named `persistent_shopping_cart`

Answer (score 5):

For me the problem had to do with the downloadable product configuration. Check settings > catalog > downloadable product.

Answer (score 3):

You have to go into the System tab, Choose Catalog from the left hand side, Choose Downloadable Product Options, and then set Disable Guest Checkout if Cart Contains Downloadable Items to No.

Answer (score 3):

Magento disables guest checkout when you enable Persistence in Config. Although I am not sure, why guest checkout has to be disabled when Persistent cart is enabled. You can find the method disableGuestCheckout that disables guest checkout in class Mage_Persistent_Model_Observer.

The simple solution would be to disable Persistent Shopping Cart in Magento configuration.
No need to change any template or override anything.

Comment: I don't think this is strictly true, I think if it finds a cookie already associated with client, it pushes login - which is a weird feature to have. But once I cleared cookies with Persistence enabled, it shows again :S

Answer (score 2):

Magento's new 'persistent shopping cart' has its own set of templates - if you've had this enabled at any point, it might be worth checking whether those templates are still being called instead of the expected set.

I just had this happen, and the persistent templates behaved true to their name, even when PSC was disabled via config.

Just override them in your custom theme files like the rest - solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

goto your magento root folder

find .htaccess file

memory limit increase to 518M

AFTER GOTO YOUR INDEX.PHP FILE

```
 ini_set("memory_limit","512M");
 echo  ini_get("memory_limit");  //for test it
```

Comment: why should someone do this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem and for me disabling terms and conditions worked. Go to System-Configuration-Checkout and set "Enable Terms and conditions" to "no", "guest checkout" and "one page checkout" to "yes". That will solve the problem.